# How to Add numbers directly on Firebase database in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

On Firebase database I have a key - "Coins" and its value - "20". Now I want to add 5 to the value (ie coins) **directly on the server**.

So every time the user clicks the button the value of Coins should increment by 5 **directly on the server**. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: sure, use "transactions" in Firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Fattie commented, you'd use [Firebase Database transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) for this. With a transaction, you get the client's best guess for the current value and return the new value based on that. So in your case:

```
coinsRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
    @Override
    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
        long value = 0;
        if (mutableData.exists()) {
            value = mutableData.getValue(Long.class);
        }
        value = value + 5;
        mutableData.setValue(value);
        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                           DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.d(TAG, "runTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
    }
});
```